# MKMapView Instruments Memory Leak in iOS10

Tags: swift, memory-leaks, mkmapview, mapkit, instruments

I've created a test project to track down a leak I'm seeing in Instruments when using MKMapView.

**Here is my MapViewController code:**

```
import UIKit
import MapKit

class MapViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var mapView: MKMapView!

    deinit {
        print(#file, #function)
    }

}
```

When I dismiss this VC, the deinit line prints, but Instruments logs a memory leak.  (Note: I'm testing on a device, not the simulator.)  The deinit tells me the mapView was deallocated properly, so I don't understand why I have a memory leak unless it's a leak in Apple's code.  Here's the Instruments screenshot.

**Instruments Screenshot :-**

[image: Screenshot]

For those curious, tracking the leak in Instruments displays the other VC in the test project, which is empty.  Below is a screenshot of that.

**Code leak pointer in Instruments:-**

[image: ScreenShot]

Is there an issue with my code, or is it an Apple code leak?  TIA

Comment: It seems that this issue is still available in iOS11.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was a bug and had been reported to Apple. It appears to have been corrected in iOS 11.